# subclass throw UnsupportedOperationException versus ignoring input parameter

Tags: java, inheritance, jdbc, subclass, liskov-substitution-principle

Let's say I have a class as below, as the class name suggests, this class doesn't allow auto commit.

So my question is that if it is better to leave it like below (empty body, maybe add some logging @WARN/ERROR level) or to throw UnsupportedOperationException?

```
public class NoAutoCommitConnection implements java.sql.Connection {
    public void setAutoCommit(boolean autoCommit) throws SQLException {
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly why are you asking? A conforming implementation of `java.sql.Connection` must always support `setAutoCommit`, not implementing it (or throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` or `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`) is not allowed by the JDBC specification. In MySQL, the MyISAM engine is non-transactional, and the driver would allow calls to `setAutoCommit`, but in practice ignore it when connected to a database using the MyISAM engine.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually go with `if(autoCommit) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }`, since it clearly communicates that auto commiting is not supported, but won't fail `setAutoCommit(false)` calls.

Not implementing the method or rather it's intention breaks the contract of the interface.

I think the least you can do in such a situation is to throw an exception at runtime.